# Spring change Map keys after autowiring

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, javabeans, autowired

I have configuration class where I create Map as Bean like this.

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Filter> filters() {
    Map<String, Filter> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("RECOMMENDATION", new RecommendationFilter());
    map.put("UPCOMING", new UpcomingFilter());
    return map;
}
```

and Autowire this map in another Service :

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Filter> filterMap;
```

in debug mode I can see that map has another keys, by the class names:

- recommendationFilter
- upcomingFilter

but not "RECOMMENDATION" and "UPCOMING", how it was setted in configuration.
And google search doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen because you might have something like this

```
@Component
class RecommendationFilter implements Filter{

}


@Component
class UpcomingFilter implements Filter{

}
```

So when you do

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Filter> filterMap;
```

spring will automagically injects instances of Filter, with bean names as the key, default bean names for the above classes are recommendationFilter and upcomingFilter.

Two solutions.

1. ```
   @Component("RECOMMENDATION")
   class RecommendationFilter implements Filter{

   }

   @Component("UPCOMING")
   class UpcomingFilter implements Filter{

   }
   ```
2. Remove `@Component` from these classes(Just word of caution. This will make them non spring beans, not sure if thats what you want)

Option 1 would be the right way to go about it. Just name the bean whatever you want as indicated above.

By creating a map explicitly you are not levaraging spring's dependency injection magic. :) (why do you want to do something which framework is doing for you, that negates the whole inversion of control (IOC) principle)